# merge dataset without duplicates R

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes in R.

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:5,5), Product = c(rep("Toaster", 3), rep("Radio", 3)))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(2, 4, 4, 6,7), State = c(rep("Alabama", 2), rep("Ohio", 3)))

loj=merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE)
```

Actual Result:

```
 CustomerId Product   State
1          1 Toaster    <NA>
2          2 Toaster Alabama
3          3 Toaster    <NA>
4          4   Radio Alabama
5          4   Radio    Ohio
6          5   Radio    <NA>
7          5   Radio    <NA>
```

Expected Result:

```
 CustomerId Product   State
1          1 Toaster    <NA>
2          2 Toaster Alabama
3          3 Toaster    <NA>
4          4   Radio Alabama
5          5   Radio    <NA>
6          5   Radio    <NA>
```

However, if you look at row 4 and 5, the entry is repeated. How can I prevent doing that? I just want the first match to be viewed and do not care about the rest of the matches that may happen in ds2. Essentially, merged should have same row count as ds1.

Thanks

Comment: It's not repeated, you have 2 different values in df2 for CustomerId == 4, can you tell us what you'd like as an output ?

Comment: `loj[!duplicated(loj$CustomerId),]` ?

Comment: I just want the first entry against CustomerId==4, not the second entry. I'm interested only in first match.

Comment: @Sotos, Sorry, I've edited the input. Also posted the actual result and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create an index vector with all duplicates that we want to remove and subset `loj` based on that `ind`

```
ind <- which(duplicated(loj$CustomerId))[1:abs(nrow(df1) - nrow(loj))]
loj[-ind,]
#  CustomerId Product   State
#1          1 Toaster    <NA>
#2          2 Toaster Alabama
#3          3 Toaster    <NA>
#4          4   Radio Alabama
#6          5   Radio    <NA>
#7          5   Radio    <NA>
```

Comment: thanks, this helps. Can we do the same by passing any function/argument in merge function so that we do not have to repeat this step?

Comment: I am not quite sure if we can do that

Answer (score 0):

Merge, then rank by group, then get 1st per group:

```
# dummy data
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:5,5),
                 Product = c(rep("Toaster", 3),
                             rep("Radio", 2),
                             "Car")) #added "car" for customer 5
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(2, 4, 4, 6,7),
                 State = c(rep("Alabama", 2), rep("Ohio", 3)))

library(dplyr)

merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(CustomerId, Product) %>% 
  filter(rank(CustomerId, ties.method = "first") == 1)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: CustomerId, Product [6]
# 
#   CustomerId Product   State
#        (dbl)  (fctr)  (fctr)
# 1          1 Toaster      NA
# 2          2 Toaster Alabama
# 3          3 Toaster      NA
# 4          4   Radio Alabama
# 5          5   Radio      NA
# 6          5     Car      NA
```

Comment: @Sotos yes, noticed it, but I don't follow OP's logic fully, why would you need to keep it, it is a duplicated row with NA values...

Comment: 'Product' column could have been different for CustomerID==5. This is just an example I created in a hurry. I want first 2 columns exactly same as ds1 and the third column from ds2, provided there is a match (only first in case of multiple match), else <NA>.

Comment: @user2778822 Then you would add `Product` into `group_by()`. See edit.